# iOS 8 app goes background in open

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

After iOS 8 release, we are getting feedback from some users about our app that whenever users try to start app, operating system navigate it to background. I was able to examine this issue myself and I see that OS does not terminate app or app does not crash. In fact, app appears in background apps menu. Whenever user tries to open the app it closes itself something as if “simulating user's home button touch”. Of course, I’m not doing something like this by code. And this issue only show 100 in 1 and only in iOS 8 devices. It shows any kind of devices from iPhone 4S to 5S.

Have you ever encounter an issue like this?

Comment: What you're seeing is a crash - check your memory footprint

Comment: Look for device crash logs.  On startup, this is sometimes due to the app blocking the main thread for too long.